# Multiple entries of Model instances in Django admin on save

Tags: javascript, python, django, heroku, uwsgi

I am running a django website on Heroku using uwsgi with 4 processes.

Often , whenever I click `save and continue editing` I get multiple entries of same instance, separated by 1-2 secs in their creation time.

What could be the issue behind this? I have even tried to prevent multiple clicks by disabling the button using javascript.

Also, the model has its save overridden . Although I dont think this makes  any difference.

Venue ModelAdmin - simple calculations and save here

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.checked_by = request.user
        if not obj.created_by:
            obj.created_by = request.user.username
        spaces = obj.venuetospacetypemapper_set.all().values('min_seating_capacity',  'max_seating_capacity')
        obj.min_seating_capacity = min([space.get('min_seating_capacity') or 0 for space in spaces] or [0])
        obj.max_seating_capacity = sum([space.get('max_seating_capacity') or 0 for space in spaces] or [0]) 
        obj.save()
```

Since there are a number of inlines in Venue admin, only
VenueMedia model has save overridden:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start=datetime.datetime.now()
        print "starting save in admin.save", start
        update_image = True
        if self.id: # if updating record, then check if image path has changed
            update_image = False
            orig = VenueMedia.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if self.url != orig.url:
                update_image = True

        print "in save in admin.save, seconds passed=", (datetime.datetime.now()-start).seconds
        if update_image:
            print "in update_image in admin.save, seconds passed=", (datetime.datetime.now()-start).seconds
            image = Img.open(StringIO.StringIO(self.url.read()))
            orignal_ratio = float(image.size[0])/image.size[1]
            new_height = int(round(orignal_ratio * 171))
            image.thumbnail((new_height,171), Img.ANTIALIAS)
            output = StringIO.StringIO()
            image.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=75)
            output.seek(0)
            self.thumbnail_url = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s" % str(self.url.name), 'image/jpeg', output.len, None)

            if not self.venueid.thumb_image_path:
                self.venueid.thumb_image_path = self.thumbnail_url
                self.venueid.save()
        print "before calling django.save in admin.save, seconds passed=", (datetime.datetime.now()-start).seconds
        super(VenueMedia, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's not JavaScript, it's most likely that an overridden save  in your model or admin that's causing the issues.

Comment: Have you overriden any of the model admin code?

Comment: yes , admin's `save_model` has been overridden

Comment: You should attach overridden save_model code to your question.

Comment: @Nick - Added the  code . Please have a look.